# How to send an image in a mail that loads on opening the mail

Tags: rest, jersey, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send a mail with an attachment using JavaMail. **My requirement is to know if the mail (purpose1)** has been opened for which I want to attach an image in the mail that should be requested from the server at the time the mail is first loaded. The server is essentially a rest host that should save a flag for the event.
I'm stuck at **how to load the image dynamically**.

Any other ideas are also welcome for **purpose1**.

Comment: Load the image where?  On the server so you can return it to the client?

Comment: @BillShannon Actually I want the image to be loaded on the client only when the user opens the mail. I want the user system to interact with my server in some way. Is that possible?

Comment: It sounded like you had that figured out.  The html body of the message includes an <img> tag that references the image on the server.  When the mailer displays the body of the message, it requests the image from the server.  (Note that many mailers will refuse to load remote images by default, so this technique doesn't always work.)

Comment: @BillShannon Actually that's the problem. If I try to add the img src as a file on the server, it is all right, but if I am to deliver it from a rest server, I'll hit the rest server at the instant I am pushing the mail from the mailer server not when the client is trying to view the image. Could you suggest something for that?

Comment: I don't understand.  How you handle the image request on the server is independent of how the image request is represented in the body of the email message.  If you use a REST server instead of a Servlet to handle the request, that doesn't change when the client makes the request.

Comment: @BillShannon Apologies for stressing on the rest part more, the simplest form of my question should be this: How am I going to make the client ask for that image from my server as soon as he opens the mail?

Comment: You aren't. The HTML renderer in the client does that.

Comment: @BillShannon Thanks for the guidance. I was not understanding my own requirement fairly. I have successfully developed it now.